# Better Efficiency in Grouped LINQ Counts

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to construct a **LINQ** query for presentation to **Microsoft Entity Framework Core**.  In my use case, I have a collection of Car records that I want to create some basic analytics.  For example

1. how many cars are in the collection?
2. How many variations of car colour does the collection contain
3. How many variations of car engine capai does the collection contain

```
var result = Cars
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(car => 1)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        NoCars = group.Select(g => g.CarId).Count(),
        NoColours = group.Select(g => g.Colour).Distinct().Count(),
        NoYears = group.Select(g => g.YearOfManufacture).Distinct().Count()
    });
```

Whilst this runs and returns the desired result, the generated SQL does not seem very efficient...

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1

-- EndRegion
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT [t3].[Id]
        FROM [Cars] AS [t3]
        WHERE ([t2].[value] = @p1) AND (/* Filter Criteria */)
        ) AS [t4]
    ) AS [NoCars], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t5].[Colour]
        FROM [Cars] AS [t5]
        WHERE ([t2].[value] = @p1) AND (/* Filter Criteria */)
        ) AS [t6]
    ) AS [NoColours], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [t7].[CapacityId]
        FROM [Cars] AS [t7]
        WHERE ([t2].[value] = @p1) AND (/* Filter Criteria */)
        ) AS [t8]
    ) AS [NoCapacities]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[value]
    FROM (
        SELECT @p0 AS [value]
        FROM [Cars] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    GROUP BY [t1].[value]
    ) AS [t2]
```

*[Script as generated by LinqPad]*

So, in practice is running a number of complete sub-queries.  In the above simple example, this may not be too problematical, but in my application, the Cars collection would be defined by a varying range of criteria.

What I was hoping to achieve was a more organised query like:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS NoCars
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT C.Colour) AS NoColours
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT C.CapacityID) AS NoCapacities
FROM Cars C
WHERE (
  /* filter criteria */
)
```

Is there a way of improving my LINQ statement?

Thanks.

Comment: What EF are you using? When I attempt a similar query with EF Core 2.2.6 it does a complete table select and does everything client side. EF Core 3.0 won't translate the query. LINQ to SQL translates the query like you showed.

Comment: I have only tested the LINQ in LinqPad at the moment.  I will test in EF Core 2.2 tomorrow.  The generated script above is from LinqPad

Comment: If you are using LINQPad 5, then your default connection is LINQ to SQL. In LINQPad 6, you can create an EF Core 2 or EF Core 3 connection to a database and then use it in queries.

Comment: Yes, LinqPad 5.  Will update.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Interesting. I will test tomorrow when I can access the dev environments. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: I have played around with LinqPad 6 and various query constructions including the `GroupBy` as shown above and also collating individual counts.  None of these seem to construct a SQL _'windows function'_ from the base query which is what I was aiming/hoping for, rather they build the whole query for each count property.

Comment: Currently, that appears to be true. EF Core is still not as capable as LINQ to SQL and unfortunately the developers appear reluctant to make (previous) capability parity a priority (or even work on it overall). However, for specific use cases you can open a bug / suggestion ticket on github.